# css :first-of-type and :last-of-type in table impacts each row individually

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, html-table

I'm trying to use jQuery datepicker to allow users to select a starting and ending date. I want it to automatically round the left edge of the first date, and the right edge of the last date (or both edges of one date, if only one is selected).

I used :first-of-type and :last-of-type, but these seem to be effecting each row of the datepicker table individually. Here's my css:

```
td.dp-highlight:first-of-type .ui-state-default {
    border-top-left-radius:1em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:1em;
}

td.dp-highlight:last-of-type .ui-state-default {
    border-top-right-radius:1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:1em;
}
```

And here it is running with the datepicker:

http://jsfiddle.net/xTaxJ/1/

Try picking a day in the middle of the week, say a Wednesday, and then pick a Wednesday two weeks from that day. You'll notice that the rounded edges are working, but on each row individually. Doesn't work at all on either Wednesday, even though they are the first and last. Also, shouldn't the first and last only fire once each? They'll wrap the edges of as many weekends as you select.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? It's driving me absolutely mad. Thanks so much!

**Edit:** Here's a picture showing what happens. http://imgur.com/ld4Sg99 The dark green days are selected in the range, and all have the class .dp-highlight. See how the edges of each row are rounded, not the actual starting and ending days? Why is that happening???

Comment: First of all, your trying to target a CSS class that doesn't exist on any of the TDs.  Your generated table is coded incorrectly because .dp-highlight is generated in your code as the content of the td rather than as a class name.

Comment: @dcc Are you sure? In the fiddle I'm seeing that, once a day is selected, the TD's classes become "dp-highlight ui-datepicker-current-day". The CSS is successfully able to highlight TDs, it's just not getting the right ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your problems is that the `:first-of-type` pseudo selector (and it's siblings, `:first-child` etc) work in the context of their container, and apply to the tag; so taking your picture for example, of all the highlighted cells, the ones that are the first of its type *in their container* are Su10 and Su17, same logic applies to `:last-of-type`.

Remember that the calendar is actually a table, so the dates selected span several rows.

What you actually want is to apply some style to the first cell in the selection, and a different one to the last, and for that I would use classes: make the first click assign a  `.date-from` class or something like that, and the second `.date-to`, with the styles you currently have.

Hope I clarified your questions :)

Comment: Thanks! I was clearly too dense to understand how first-of-type etc work, but your explanation was very helpful! I was hoping that I could get away without having to assign classes (which would then need to be removed), but it's good to know for sure that CSS alone isn't going to be an option here.

Comment: When I try to add a class to either the TD or the A itself, it's immediately getting overwritten by the datepicker. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's something called "CSS Specificity", so you want to make the rule as specific as possible, like `td.dp-highlight.from-date .ui-state-default`, extending from the previous rule.